# How to set to true / false based on react props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
const [effective_date_status, setEffectiveDateStatus] = React.useState(false)
```

I'm sending props value from parent to child. I want to set **effective_date_status** to **`false`** if props value is **`0`** & I want to set to **`true`** if props value is **`1`**.

Can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as:

```
const [effective_date_status, setEffectiveDateStatus] = React.useState(
  !!props.value
);
```

or

```
const [effective_date_status, setEffectiveDateStatus] = React.useState(
  props.value === 0 ? false : true
);
```

or **`Lazy Initialisation`**

```
const [effective_date_status, setEffectiveDateStatus] = React.useState(() =>
  props.value === 0 ? false : true
);
```

Comment: **Lazy Initialization** worked for my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

first, import use effect hook and then try this

```
useEffect(()=>{
if(props.value === 1)
setEffectiveDateStatus(true);
else if(props.value === 0)
setEffectiveDateStatus(false);
},[props.value])
```